# What is invovled in adding an SSL certificate to provide https?

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, process

I struggle at asking the right questions correctly.

I'm working on a site that will require some information like name/address to be entered into a form.  I would like this form to receive it's data encrypted.

What is the process invovled in purchase and applying an SSL cert so that users can feel secure when entering private information?

I'm on a shared host that uses cpanel.

From a little research, I see I can go buy a certificate at varying prices for varying terms.  Just wondering what to do after I get the cert.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you purchase a Cert from a trusted provider you must generate a CSR (certificate signing request). In your case this can be done through the CPanel interface as described here:

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/GenerateCert

Once done copy-paste the CSR into the purchase wizard at the SSL provider you choose. Be careful about which email address and domain name you enter for the CSR. Also, read the SSL providers CSR directions requirements as well.

Once the SSL has been generated you just go back to CPanel and copy-paste or upload it. Directions are simple and should also be in the aforementioned wiki.

Comment: Great, exactly the direction I was looking for.  I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

From within CPANEL you need to go to the

```
SSL / TLS Manager
```

From there is everything you need to generate a request and upload a private key and/or certificate.